# HtmlUnit and button

Tags: java, button, htmlunit

I'm trying to submit with a form but the button does not have a name, here's my code so far:

```
try {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(baseURL);

        HtmlSubmitInput button = ?

        HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

        System.out.println(page2.asXml());
```

And this is the HTML button text:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

How can i assign it to my button variable without it having a name?

Comment: You can access your element by document.getElementByClassname() or document.getElementById()

Comment: My Html page doesnt have any of those methods available, what class is that from?

Comment: document.getElementByClassname() is a JAvascript method

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this by xpath:

```
HtmlSubmitInput button = page.getFirstByXPath(".//span//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]")
```

**Note:** This will only work if there are not other button present which text contain 'Submit' word. For multiple similar button you should use `getByXPath` which will return a list than iterate the list to collect the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Getting Started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html). The section '*Finding a specific element*' outlines the different ways to find elements. At least there is a rich api to traverse the dom.